# Question about Type Comparison ASP.NET and DBNull

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dbnull

I have a function that pulls articles records from an MSSQL database. Some are URLs to PDFs, and other are actual articles stored in the SQL. The articles that are stored do not have a URL (DBNull) in the record, so I want to be able to parse that. I tried a simple test:

```
If Row.Item("url").GetType Is GetType(DBNull) Then
    //' do something here....
End If
```

However, I get the "`Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.`" exception.  The funny part is, when I do a watch on the above conditional, it returns `True` or `False`.

Anyone know why this is happening and/or a way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
If Row.IsNull("url") Then
    //' do something here....
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I always just use this test on the record:

```
If IsDBNull(strSQLTiggRes("url")) Then
     'Do something                   .
Else
     'do something else
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

I like

```
if (DBNull.Value.Equals(Row.Item("url")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
If Row.Item("url") = DBNull.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `Row.Item("url")` is a `System.String` so the value at this point will not by `DbNull`.

Try something like this:

```
If Row.Item("url") Is Nothing Then
    //' do something here....
End If
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite right - the expression "Row.Item("url").GetType" would still evaluate to a System.Type and the overall expression would just evaluate to False.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do

```
If Row.Item("url") = DBNull.Value Then

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference is:

```
If Not Object.Equals(DBNull.Value, Row.Item("url")) Then
  'Hooray!
End If
```

In VB, you can also use the `IsDBNull` function (`Microsoft.VisualBasic` disclaimer) directly :

```
If Not IsDBNull(Row.Item("url")) Then
  'Hooray!
End It
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
if row("ColumnName") is DBNull.value Then
     'do something
end if
```

You will find that you must use is in this case and you nee dto compare the values not just the types. You may also want to put it into a reusable function that you can use to return nothing instead of dbnull

```
function checkvalue(item as object)
     if item is dbnul.value then
          return nothing
     else
          return item
     end if
 end function
```